# Share my app to another installed app in android

Tags: android

i'm a new android developer. I have an application installed in phone. This application has a Save button to save info after input... When user click Save button, it displays a dialog to choose where to save (in Contact, in gmail contact). I wish to create an application to add to this save dialog to save info from that application to my own application. Is it possible to do that? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to invoke your own application with data, set your flag exported= activity to be invoked to true, in manifest file, or set some intent filter on activity, and call your activity with that intent.

See, link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html